# What can you tell me about integrable functions and riemann integrals?

Tags: analysis, definition

Define the concepts of integrable function and Riemann integral for functions of two 
variables (across a rectangle and over an arbitrary area).

I know how to define for a rectangle but not an arbitrary area.

EDIT:

Are the following correct?

In order for a function to be integrable, you have to function is limited and defined in a rectangle, and that for each real number e> 0 exists two staircase functions such that 
g (x, y) <= f (x, y) <= h (x, y) 
and 
Doubble integral of g (x, y) - Doubble integral of h (x, y) < e

The riemann integral of such a function is the double integral of funtionen f over the rectangle?

For an arbitrary area D, the function must be continuous in D and every (x, y) in D must be of the form p(x) <= y <= r(x), a <= x <= b.

D is compact => f is uniform continuous and bounded on D.

Brink (don't know if it's the right name in english) of D is a null set since p(x) and r(x) are continuous. Therefore, f is integrable over D ?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Usually the integral of a function over an arbitary area can be expressed by a double integral $\int \int f(x,y)dxdy$ , which can be written as a composition of two normal riemann integrals $\int (\int f(x,y) dx) dy$. The limits of the outer integral might depend on x. For special areas, this problem can be avoided with special coordinates (like polar coordinates for a circle). In this case, the integral simply is the product of two normal riemann integrals.

Comment: The calculation might be very difficult, if arbitary areas are allowed.

Comment: Sorry i did not see your reply. But I am thinking right :)? I were supposed only going to write down the definitions. I forgot my book at a friend so it's a little bit hard to study without a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an arbitrary area, you consider every possible way to get finitely many disjoint small rectangles that are contained in your rectangle, and compute the min value of the function in each rectangle and add up the weighted areas. The supremum over all choices of rectangles gives you a lower bound for your integral. Then you similarly compute the infimum over all choices of rectangles when you take the max value of the function within each rectangle, to get an upper bound for your integral. If the lower and upper bounds agree then the function is integrable over the area and the integral value is equal to the upper/lower bound.

Comment: A good approach!

Comment: could you check my edit and see if it's could be a definition?